# How to fetch the modified rows after comparing 2 versions of same data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a script for reading a CSV file today and comparing it with the yesterday's file of same data.

This CSV gets uploaded on the server once daily, and I want to compare today's and yesterday's files.

I want to know the rows which were modified, Inserted or Deleted by comparing these 2 files.

I have done it for Inserts and Deletes, but I am struggling with Modify.

Below is the code for getting INSERT and DELETE Dataframes:

```py
def getInsDel(df_old,df_new,key):
    #concatinating old and new data to generate comparisons
    df = pd.concat([df_new,df_old])
    df= df.reset_index(drop = True)


    #doing a group by for getting the frequency of each key
    print('Grouping data for frequency of key...')
    df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))
    idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
    df_delta = df.reindex(idx)
    df_delta_freq = df_delta.groupby(key).size().reset_index(name='Freq')

    #Filtering data for frequency = 1, since these will be the target records for DELETE and INSERT 
    print('Creating data frame to get records with Frequency = 1  ...')
    filter = df_delta_freq['Freq']==1
    df_delta_freq_ins_del = df_delta_freq.where(filter)


    #Dropping row with NULL
    df_delta_freq_ins_del = df_delta_freq_ins_del.dropna()


    print('Creating data frames of Insert and Deletes  ...')
    #Creating INSERT dataFrame 
    df_ins = pd.merge(df_new, 
                     df_delta_freq_ins_del[key],
                     on = key,
                     how = 'inner'
                    )

    #Creating DELETE dataFrame
    df_del = pd.merge(df_old, 
                     df_delta_freq_ins_del[key],
                     on = key,
                     how = 'inner'
                    )

    print('size of INSERT file: ' + str(df_ins.shape))
    print('size of DELETE file: ' + str(df_del.shape))


    return df_ins,df_del
```

For example, 
Old data is:

```
ID  Name  X  Y
1   ABC   1  2
2   DEF   2  3
3   HIJ   3  4
```

and new data set is:

```
ID  Name   X   Y
2   DEF    2   3
3   HIJ    55  42
4   KLM    4   5
```

Where ID is the Key.

Modified_DataFrame should be:

```
ID   Name   X   Y
3    HIJ   55   42
```

NOTE: See here that ID - 1,2 would be in the DELETE dataframe and ID - 4 would be in INSERT DataFrame. This part I have done by grouping based on key and then filtering out based on the frequency of these keys. If the Frequency is 1, then I know its either DELETE or INSERT.

However, What can be done to get the Modified_dataFrame?

### EDIT

After taking reference from the link in comments, after some modifications, I have added the MODIFY_DataFrame as below:

```py
    df_all = pd.concat([df_new,df_old],ignore_index=True)
    cols_list = list(df_all)
    modifcations = df_all.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_list, keep='last')
    mod_keys = modifcations[modifcations[key].duplicated() == True][key]

    df_mod = pd.merge(df_new, 
                     mod_keys[key],
                     on = key,
                     how = 'inner'
                    )

    print('size of MODIFY file: ' + str(df_mod.shape))
```

Thanks all!

Comment: https://pbpython.com/excel-diff-pandas-update.html check this blog post out!

Comment: @Datanovice: Thanks a lot! I modified the stuff in link and used it for solution.

Comment: No problem you should post your answer as answer and accept it. Make it clear so others can benefit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking reference from the link in comments, after some modifications, I have added the MODIFY_DataFrame as below:

```py
    df_all = pd.concat([df_new,df_old],ignore_index=True)
    cols_list = list(df_all)
    modifcations = df_all.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_list, keep='last')
    mod_keys = modifcations[modifcations[key].duplicated() == True][key]

    df_mod = pd.merge(df_new, 
                     mod_keys[key],
                     on = key,
                     how = 'inner'
                    )

    print('size of MODIFY file: ' + str(df_mod.shape))
```

Thanks all!