# Faster way of comparing 2 similar Data Frames for differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This in continuation to my previous question:
[How to fetch the modified rows after comparing 2 versions of same data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153549/how-to-fetch-the-modified-rows-after-comparing-2-versions-of-same-data-frame)

I am now done with the MODIFICATIONS, however, I am using below method for finding the INSERTS and DELETES.
It work fine, however, it takes a lot of time. Typically for a CSV file which has 10 columns and 10M rows.

For my problem, 
INSERT are the records which are not in old file, but in new file.
DELETE are the records which are in old file, but not in new file.

Below is the code:

```py
def getInsDel(df_old,df_new,key):
    #concatinating old and new data to generate comparisons
    df = pd.concat([df_new,df_old])
    df= df.reset_index(drop = True)


    #doing a group by for getting the frequency of each key
    print('Grouping data for frequency of key...')
    df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))
    idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
    df_delta = df.reindex(idx)
    df_delta_freq = df_delta.groupby(key).size().reset_index(name='Freq')

    #Filtering data for frequency = 1, since these will be the target records for DELETE and INSERT 
    print('Creating data frame to get records with Frequency = 1  ...')
    filter = df_delta_freq['Freq']==1
    df_delta_freq_ins_del = df_delta_freq.where(filter)


    #Dropping row with NULL
    df_delta_freq_ins_del = df_delta_freq_ins_del.dropna()


    print('Creating data frames of Insert and Deletes  ...')
    #Creating INSERT dataFrame 
    df_ins = pd.merge(df_new, 
                     df_delta_freq_ins_del[key],
                     on = key,
                     how = 'inner'
                    )

    #Creating DELETE dataFrame
    df_del = pd.merge(df_old, 
                     df_delta_freq_ins_del[key],
                     on = key,
                     how = 'inner'
                    )

    print('size of INSERT file: ' + str(df_ins.shape))
    print('size of DELETE file: ' + str(df_del.shape))


    return df_ins,df_del
```

The section where I am doing a group by for the frequency of each key, it takes around 80% of the total time, so for my CSV it takes around 12-15 mins.

There must be a faster approach for doing this?

For your reference, below is my result expectation:

For example, Old data is:

```
ID  Name  X  Y
1   ABC   1  2
2   DEF   2  3
3   HIJ   3  4
```

and new data set is:

```
ID  Name   X   Y
2   DEF    2   3
3   HIJ    55  42
4   KLM    4   5
```

Where ID is the Key.

Insert_DataFrame should be:

```
ID   Name   X   Y
4    KLM    4   5
```

Deleted_DataFrame should be:

```
ID   Name   X   Y
1    ABC    1   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## to be deleted

```
delete=pd.merge(old,new,how='left',on='ID',indicator=True)
delete=delete.loc[delete['_merge']=='left_only']
delete.dropna(1,inplace=True)
```

## to be inserted

```
insert=pd.merge(new,old,how='left',on='ID',indicator=True)
insert=insert.loc[insert['_merge']=='left_only']
insert.dropna(1,inplace=True)
```